# Authentic Kula tantra books mentioning methods to achieve brahman using Sex or masturbation

Tags: tantra

I want to know if any authentic tantra books (like kaulavali tantra or others like this who people of nath tradition or other tantric schools like mishra , kula etc ) mention ways of achieving the realization or glimpse of brahman using techniques such as masturbation or sex.

I know these things are strictly passed through word of mouth in a guru shishya parampara so even if the books do mention these they wont work or they wont mention the exact ways of doing it but I just want to know does tantra really hold a way to achieve brahman easily in only 1 lifetime using these techniques which normally takes atleast 3 or 4 lifetimes of sincerely doing right hand patanjali raja yoga in an isolated spot to get a glimpse of brahman and go into nirvikalpa/savikalpa samadhi when using tantra under a qualified person can make me realise the non dual reality using things like sex or masturbation or whatever etc ?

There are lots of stories of people like for example milarepa who learned tantra and became free from birth and death in a single lifetime i dont know if he used sex etc to do it but he did use tantra.

So please just tell me if there are authentic books which do indeed mention if it is possible to achieve liberation in just 1 lifetime provided we find a person who himself is enlightened and knows techniques to guide others too towards brahman.

Comment: An eminent Dashanami Sanyasi - Agehananda Bharati has conformed these practicres are real.  Arthur Avalon might have written about this  @DeepanshuMolasi

Comment: @S kYes read books of avalon not in detail but those are just introductions to tantra they just explain things like all types of chakras , basic theory of shiva and shakti and panchamakara but other than that doesn't explcitly say how to gain samadhi using techniques althought I may be wrong since i havent read all his books in detail just saw a few pages. Anyway thanks for replying S K